# MySQL Better to FULLTEXT a lot of columns or one with concat'ed data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 58 columns of data that need to be searchable. Changes to the data is rare (handful of times per year).

Is it better to add FULLTEXT index to each column, or create a column and concatenate all row data into one column with FULLTEXT?

Use case is an infrequently changing product database for a website with relatively low traffic. Products have a lot of attributes which will require filtering/sorting/searching. Doing initial research for best approach.

Currently using Node / Sequelize ORM just to fetch predefined sets of data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample query or two. The indexes you choose depend largely  on your queries.

Comment: Searching a concatenated string requires generating that concatenated string, which is extra overhead. Searching to see if `bcd` appears in `abc` and `def` yields a different result to searching `abcdef`. Equally, there are only two three character sequences to search in `abc` and `def`, but there are 4 three character sequences in `abcdef` to check.  This strongly strikes me as premature optimisation; if the strings are separate, search them as separate strings.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the concatenated column (or a seperate search table) is better. I don't know how the performance will improve or decrease, but I think that part is mostly micro optimization.

However, your queries will be much cleaner if you have to look at only a single WHERE statement instead of 58.

Also, I think it would be better for seperation of dependencies if you have a seperate script which will know about the 58 columns and updates concatenated column periodically, whereas the script that searches that table doesn't have to be aware of all those columns.

Ofcourse, all this totally depends on the actual usecase.
Depending on the usecase I would consider not searching the database at all, but using something like Elastic instead.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Updated question with use case. I am using an ORM so that'll help substantially with query construction if I did continue that route. Something like Elastic is what initially came to mind. Not quite sure of requirements yet, this is just initial research.